# Not able to remove UI element on click in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am going through various examples and tried few of them but unable to delete it from UI level.
I tried using `*ngFor`. So ngFor is only removing `<span>`,  not `<buttons>` in `<li>` tags.Then I tried with indexing but no success yet.

```
<div>
  <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li  *ngFor="let item of todos; let i = index" class="todo-item">
      <span [ngClass]="{ inactive: item.done }">{{ item.value }}</span>

      <button class="todo-item-button" (click)="editUser()">Edit</button>
      <button class="todo-delete-button" (click)="deleteUser(item,i)">Delete</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*Component:-*

```
todos: Todo[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
this.todos = this.todoService.getAllTodos();
}

deleteUser(todos ,index: number) {
    this.todoService.deleteIndexDb(todos.id)
    .subscribe(
      () => {
        this.todos.splice(index, 1);
      });
  }
```

Need little help in this.

Comment: You'd need to make Angular believe the variable has been changed so that it can trigger change detection. Try reassigning the variable: `this.todos = this.todos.splice(index, 1);`

Comment: Your story sounds very unlikely. I think you should try to figure out what is actually going on. For example: add {{i}} inside the *ngFor template and see if the index actually gets removed.

Comment: @MichaelD Hi I have tried this before . Not working

Comment: I think that your problem is that your deleteIndexDb not return an observable, so you can not subscribe and not executed the splice

Comment: @Eliseo Agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reassign it with the spread syntax

```
deleteUser(todos ,index: number) {
    this.todoService.deleteIndexDb(todos.id)
    .subscribe(
      () => {
        this.todos.splice(index, 1);
        this.todos = [...this.todos]
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the reference to your `todos` array in order for Angular change detection to work. `Array.splice` is not the best option, as it doesn't create a new array. You can use `Array.filter` or `Array.map`:

```
deleteUser(todos ,index: number) {
    this.todoService.deleteIndexDb(todos.id)
    .subscribe(
      () => {
        this.todos = this.todos.map((item, i) => {
          if (i !== index) {
            return item;
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

changing values of type Object wont trigger the change detection, Arrays are treated as Objects in Javascript. So you need to assign back the new array which is returned from the splice method to todos object as shown below.

```
//ES5`enter code here`
this.todos.splice(index, 1);
this.todos = new Array(this.todos);
//ES6
this.todos.splice(index, 1);
this.todos = [...this.todos];
```

Comment: Almonst in Angular 12 it's not true (I think that in older Angular versions you're correct), check the simple stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fwlvgh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts